# Bootstrap 4 : Add a subtitle to a modal

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm actually building a web site and I use Bootstrap since it's very efficient and ensure a possibility for everyone to know how my website works.

But the fact is that I'm trying to use a modal to display some stuffs and I need to put in this one a subtitle, I've already tried few stuffs but any of them was working properly.

My ideal modal would look like this :

[image: My ideal modal]

I guess the solution is in the HTML & CSS files but I'm a newbie to those work ways so even with reading the Bootstrap official CSS modal's page I didn't managed to find the way to do it.

### I've already tried :

- Adding another title `div` inside of the modal header and editing a bit the css but didn't managed to get what I'm looking for

  - tried using the `width` property to force the title to take the whole row but didn't worked.
  - tried using the `justify-content` attribute since we're using flexboxes but didn't worked too.
- Adding directly an other title (`h5`) inside of the header, but had the same result than for the `div`

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Please post the code you've attempted. We can't help if we don't understand what you've tried, and the explanation in the question doesn't help. "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."

Comment: Hi, I added a precise picture of what I'm looking for, in order to be clearer, thanks for the piece of advise you gave in your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For title and subtitle with margin you can give padding left. For example:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<h2 class="pl-2">Sub Title</h2>
```

To demonstrate further, I created a sample modal for you
Go to: https://www.pateladitya.com/stackoverflow/modal-sample-dual-title.html

I think the issue you are having is in some css. Check if you have not made your title and sub-title to show inline.

Comment: It isn't what I'm looking for, in bootstrap, it isn't possible to do it like this in an modal.

Comment: Can you share your code somewhere? Maybe provide a link.

Comment: I added a picture of what I'm looking for on top of the post, thanks for your work mate but it isn't what I'm really looking for.

Comment: Okay, got your point. I have updated the above link with what you wanted. The problem was that modal-title is set to display: flex by default. So what I did was made it to display block and created a div structure within it.

Comment: Thanks mate ! That was what I was looking for, I appreciate your participation.
I think the way to do it is kind of similar but have you got an idea to properly display a footer on the left part of the one which already exists ? (as i pictured on my image). Thanks once more, you helped me a lot mate.

Comment: You're Welcome. It is what the community is for. I have updated the link with what you wanted.

Comment: Can you please accept it as the answer so it gets resolved

Answer (score 5):

The dom displays a subtitle for me using bootstrap 4 with the following jsx:

```html
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">SUPER TITLE
        <br>
        <small>SUB-TITLE</small>
    </h4>
</div>
```

Also, in my testing nesting `h5` (sub-title) inside of `h4` also worked... So I'm surprised it didn't work for you. However, I didn't post that answer because it also throws a warning if you try nesting headers:

> Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): react `<h5>` cannot appear as a child of `<h4>`

Comment: Another nice thing about this approach is that if you want a smaller or bigger title, the subtitle doesn't need any adjusting, as it will always be relatively `small`er, thus avoiding any code change.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with Flexbox?

```
<div style="flex-direction:column;">
   <h1 class="modal-title">Title</h5>
   <h2>Sub Title</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but instead of style I prefer to use class: `<div class="flex-column">`

Answer (score 0):

You are currently on h4 element so the easiest you can do for yourself is to decrease your heading to maybe h2 or h1, right until you are satisfied.